# Touchpad while holding on touchpad it doesn't work

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, lenovo, thinkpad

When I'm holding (not pressing) the bottom line of the touchpad (where the mouse buttons are) I can't move the touchpad. This:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

worked but then my two finger scrolling isn't working anymore.
Maybe there are some synclient settings I should adjust?

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and a lenovo thinkpad touchpad

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? You can use `libinput` instead of `xorg-synaptics` to fix the issue.

Comment: @Pilot6 how can I use libinput to fix this? I'm new to touchpads ;D

Comment: @Merduma From your other questions I assume this is about the Thinkpad E470. Did you also have problems with the middle mouse button?

Comment: @userone470 yes

Comment: Looking at your dmesg log you will probably notice a warning "failed to get extended button data" (at least mine does). So there seems to be a bug in the psmouse kernel module (or in the Thinkpad E470 ps2 interface). The psmouse module can be patched so that it assumes a third trackpoint button is present. See https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=100694

Comment: Hmm, I'm having this issue on 17.04 with libinput, and running that command fixes the middle scroll but then breaks touchpad rejection for the clickpad button areas (theT440s doesn't have real trackpoint buttons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install `libinput` that in most cases solves the problem. Run in a terminal

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-libinput
```

and reboot.